# Why is this parsing from BeautifulSoup throwing error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have this HTML source:- `http://pastebin.com/itMYaimq`. I am running the following BeautifulSoup command to parse the HTML

```
def check_img(self, feed):
        return 1 if feed.find_all('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: 'data' not in x}) else 0
```

Here the `feed` is the HTML source.

Upon execution this throws.

```
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,415: WARNING/Worker-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,415: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/data_processors/rule_processor.py", line 58, in do_akamai_analysis
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,416: WARNING/Worker-2] resp, self.analysis.url, self.analysis.id)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,416: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/rules.py", line 794, in akamai_rule_analysis
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,416: WARNING/Worker-2] result[RULES.FEO_CHECKS] = check_feo_optimizations(analysis_id, url)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,417: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/rules.py", line 1320, in check_feo_optimizations
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,417: WARNING/Worker-2] return FEO_processor.FEOProcessor().process_feo_debug_output(analysis_id, url)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,417: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/data_processors/FEO_processor.py", line 38, in process_feo_debug_output
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,417: WARNING/Worker-2] self.result[name] = (False, True)[getattr(self,func)(feed)]
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,418: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/data_processors/FEO_processor.py", line 64, in check_img
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,418: WARNING/Worker-2] return 1 if feed.find_all('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: 'data' not in x}) else 0
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,418: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1180, in find_all
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,419: WARNING/Worker-2] return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,419: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 505, in _find_all
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,419: WARNING/Worker-2] found = strainer.search(i)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,420: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1540, in search
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,420: WARNING/Worker-2] found = self.search_tag(markup)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,420: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1512, in search_tag
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,421: WARNING/Worker-2] if not self._matches(attr_value, match_against):
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,421: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1578, in _matches
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,421: WARNING/Worker-2] return match_against(markup)
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,421: WARNING/Worker-2] File "/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/data_processors/FEO_processor.py", line 64, in <lambda>
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,422: WARNING/Worker-2] return 1 if feed.find_all('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: 'data' not in x}) else 0
[2015-01-08 10:19:16,422: WARNING/Worker-2] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not itterable
```

I have printed the `feed` to see it's value. It printed the HTML source so it's not `None`. So why do I get this error as `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: If `feed` would be `None`, you'd get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`. Are you sure about what's in `x`? `'data' not in None` would give `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.

Comment: x should have whatever is there is `src` attribute of an `img` tag

Comment: You can see the HTML here http://pastebin.com/itMYaimq

Comment: Did you type up this traceback by hand? You have a spelling mistake in `iterable`...

Comment: The `img` tag in line 1885 doesn't have a `src` attribute. And that's only the first of many.

Comment: Please don't self-vandalise your posts; I put work into answering your question and others may find it useful too. You licensed your question to the site when you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Your `src` lambda is testing against `None`:

```
>>> x = None
>>> 'data' not in x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

This happens when you are trying to validate against a `<img>` tag that has no `src` attribute; your input source has 8 such tags:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=itMYaimq').content)
>>> len(soup.find_all('img', src=False))
8
```

Simply test for that:

```
lambda x: x and 'data' not in x
```

Your test can be simplified; there is no need to find **all** matches, just a first one:

```
blzsrc_image = feed.find('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: 'data' not in x})
return 1 if blzsrc_image else 0
```

If a boolean will do (rather than `1` or `0`) you can use:

```
blzsrc_image = feed.find('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: 'data' not in x})
return blzsrc_image is not None
```